# Componentwise convergence of infinite matrix when considered as a bounded operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

For an infinite matrix $A = (a_{ij})_{i,j \in \mathbb{N}}$ set $\lVert A \rVert := \sup_i \sum_j |a_{ij}| \in [0, \infty]$. Then for $\mu \in \ell^1$ considered as a row vector the left multiplication $\mu A$ is defined and moreover $\mu A \in \ell^1$. Similarly, for $f \in \ell^\infty$ the right multiplication $Af$ is defined and we have $Af \in \ell^\infty$. The matrix $A$ acts on $\ell^1$ and $\ell^\infty$ as a bounded linear operator.

Let $A^{(n)} = (a^{(n)}_{ij})_{i,j \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of infinite matrices such that $\lVert A^{(n)} \rVert < \infty$ for all $n$. Is it true that if $A^{(n)}_{ij} \to 0$ for all $i, j$ then $\mu A^{(n)} f \to 0$ for all $\mu \in \ell^1$ and $f \in \ell^\infty$?

Comment: I didn't read with much attention, frankly, but I think that the answer is negative. Imagine an infinite matrix with only one entry being equal to $1$. Construct a sequence of matrices in which this 1 travels to infinity. Here's an example of a sequence of matrices in which the entries converge to 0 pointwise but the corresponding operators do not converge to 0.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you. Of course. Then I don't quite understand Tao's statement "... extract a subsequence {T_{n_k} = (a_{i,j,n_k})_{i,j \geq 1}} that converges componentwise (i.e. in the weak operator topology) ..." here:
https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/finitary-consequences-of-the-invariant-subspace-problem/

Comment: I overlooked that $\mu\in \ell^1$. So in particular $\mu(n)\to 0$, which kills the "traveling 1 " example I sketched above. I think that what you conjecture is true.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro The "traveling 1" example is fine. Set $A^{(n)}_{ij} := n$ if $i = 1$ and $j = n$ (first row of $A$ is $(0, \dots, 0, n, 0, \dots)$ with $n$ at the $j$-th position and all other rows are $0$). Then $A^{(n)}_{ij} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for each fixed component $i, j$. Set $\mu := \delta_1 = (1, 0, \dots) \in \ell^1$ and $f := (1, 1, \dots) \in \ell^\infty$. Then $\mu A^{(n)} f = n \to \infty$.

Comment: But that sequence is not uniformly bounded

Comment: Uniform boundedness was not required. But even if we set $A^{(n)} _{1,n} = 1$ we get a counterexample with uniform boundedness. Would be interesting to know which extra property can improve componentwise convergence to WOT convergence.

Comment: Hmm. My intuition would be that WOT convergence should be equivalent to pointwise convergence + some sort of uniform boundedness condition. The traveling 1 example should be weakly convergent to 0.